# Chrome is not cachig content served by SSL

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, nginx, https, varnish

I'm developing a web site and i have setting up the following structure in production eviroment:

NGINX (listening 443,proxy_pass) -> Varnish (listening 80) -> NGINX (listenig 8080).

So i can serve via https cached content.

The problem is that i have noticed that google crome is not caching locally content served via SSL (Firefox does)

When i pointed to the 80 port , both, Firefox and Chrome caches the content but chrome does not cache when try 443.

Those are the headers i get for a testing image:

---

**Serving by HTTP**

Accept-Ranges:bytes

Age:28

Cache-Control:max-age=31536000

Content-Length:190667

Content-Type:image/jpeg

Date:Fri, 18 Dec 2015 12:06:49 GMT

ETag:"5673f678-2e8cb"

Expires:Sat, 17 Dec 2016 12:06:49 GMT

Last-Modified:Fri, 18 Dec 2015 12:05:12 GMT

---

**Served by HTTPS**

Accept-Ranges:bytes

Age:74

Cache-Control:max-age=31536000

Connection:keep-alive

Content-Length:190667

Content-Type:image/jpeg

Date:Fri, 18 Dec 2015 12:19:34 GMT

ETag:"5673f678-2e8cb"

Expires:Sat, 17 Dec 2016 12:06:49 GMT

Last-Modified:Fri, 18 Dec 2015 12:05:12 GMT

---

Anyone knows if this may be a config problem with my servers, or maybe its a chrome normal way of deal with SSL conections?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked with some other ssl server?

Comment: Do you think it can be because of the "Connection:keep-alive" header that nginx generates?

Comment: I mean, check with someone else's server, like `google.com`. And how do you know, that chrome does not cache?

Comment: ahhh! Ok.. i try with stackoverflow and chrome caches content even via SSL. So it must be somethig with mi conf... i think something about the keep-alive conection header. But there is no way to disble it in nginx

Comment: I check that is not caching with the chrome developments tools (F12).

Comment: when content is cached you can see (from cache) in the network tab

Comment: Didn't you turn on `disable cache` checkbox in dev tools?

Comment: i didn't, and when i try with other ssl web pages as you suggest, my chrome caches without problem, so is not a mather of my chrome config.

Comment: Given that there is an etag, does chrome send a request off for the content and get a 304 not modified?

Comment: When i get the test image using the 80 port, then i get a '304 not modified' But when i try with 443 i get with a "200 Ok" status code

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the problem.

i remove from the response headers the "Vary: cookies" header and now chrome is locally caching the content served via HTTPS

Comment: Hi Can you explain how you did that, I'm having the same problem. Thanks!